# Unity.mvc5 - Registering Session object

Tags: c#, session, unity-container, registration

I have a ISessionState interface

```
public interface ISessionState
{
    void Clear();
    void Delete(string key);
    object Get(string key);
    T Get<T>(string key) where T : class;
    ISessionState Store(string key, object value);
}
```

and SessionState class:

```
public class SessionState : ISessionState
{
    private readonly HttpSessionStateBase _session;

    public SessionState(HttpSessionStateBase session)
    {
        _session = session;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _session.RemoveAll();
    }

    public void Delete(string key)
    {
        _session.Remove(key);
    }

    public object Get(string key)
    {
        return _session[key];
    }

    public T Get<T>(string key) where T : class
    {
        return _session[key] as T;
    }

    public ISessionState Store(string key, object value)
    {
        _session[key] = value;

        return this;
    }
}
```

a BaseController class:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    private readonly ISessionState _sessionState;
    protected BaseController(ISessionState sessionState)
    {
        _sessionState = sessionState;
    }

    internal protected ISessionState SessionState
    {
        get { return _sessionState; }
    }
}
```

and user controller:

```
public class UserController : BaseController
{
    public UserController(ISessionState sessionState) : base(sessionState) { }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // clear the session and add some data
        SessionState.Clear();
        SessionState.Store("key", "some value");

        return View();
    }
}
```

I use Unity for dependency injection. This registration:

```
container.RegisterType<ISessionState, SessionState>();
```

or

```
container.RegisterType<ISessionState, SessionState>(new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<HttpSessionStateBase>("session")));
```

results: The current type, System.Web.HttpSessionStateBase, is an abstract class and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

What is the right solution for registration with unity.mvc5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to fix this is to register `HttpSessionStateBase` like this:

```
container.RegisterType<HttpSessionStateBase>(
    new InjectionFactory(x =>
        new HttpSessionStateWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session)));
```

This will provide the session based on the current web request, which I assume is what you want.

Comment: Its a good solution. I managed to solve it with Castle.Core nuget, but this is more clear. Thank you!